# Spring boot configuration in a multi-Module maven project intellij

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm having a problem properly setting up spring boot for my multi-module maven project.

I am trying to create a multi module project that contains two module, core and module tierce. the core is based on spring boot (tomcat)

parent Pom
 -|-----------Core module(spring boot)
 -|----------- Module tierce

My quiestion is how to configure and run the application using this tomcat servelt container under a maven multi moduls project.

My parent pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <!--The packaging is defined as ‘pom’ to tell maven not to package-->
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>pfe Soliam Monitoring</name>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>tierce</module>
  </modules>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </pluginManagement> 
  </build>

  <dependencies>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

pom.xml file core module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>core</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>

            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        </properties>




    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.intrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.intrace</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>com.oracle</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>11.2.0.1.0</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.opendmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxremote_optional</artifactId>
            <version>1.0_01-ea</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.Final</version>

        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

tierce pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>tierce</groupId>
    <artifactId>tierce</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>parent</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.goebl</groupId>
            <artifactId>david-webb</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

the running class based on spring boot(starting tomcat)

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @Component

    public class coreApplication {

        databaseConnectionImpl dbconn = new databaseConnectionImpl();

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            SpringApplication.run(coreApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing first for the solution but are you trying to leverage the functionality in the artifact tierce within core? If so you still need to still declare that artifact in your dependencies on core. Or if core is a base for building a number of applications then you would include core into your tierce project and start the application from there.

Just by having a multi-maven module has no bearing on how dependencies are exposed on the classpath.

Comment: core use class(service) implemented in the module tierce, core module will lanch the application